# Getting the abstract syntax tree of a C program with GCC

Tags: gcc, c

How to get abstract syntax tree of a C program with GCC?

I'm trying to automatically insert OpenMP pragmas to the input C program. I need to analyze nested for loops to find dependencies so that I can insert appropriate OpenMP pragmas.

So basically what I want to traverse and analyze the abstract syntax tree of the input C program.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Look at the plugin feature of gcc if you absolutely want to use gcc, but I think looking at clang is a better option. (BTW, I fail to see how this is Unix or Linux related).

Answer (score 1):

Use clang with `-ast-print` option, this is the cleanest way to do it.